# Is there anything to convert HTML special characters in files to normal characters?

Tags: html, character-encoding, special-characters

I have some source code files which came to me by an HTML output, so they're pretty unusable.

I have things like this:

```
%include &quot;macros.mac&quot;
```

Which should be:

```
%include "macros.mac"
```

Is there any script (sh, perl, batch, ...) to convert every file (there are about 200) to the appropriate characters? Characters include `& lt;`, `& gt;`, ... (I put an space in the middle so that it wont convert them to < and >.

Thank you, it's very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just about the four `&"<>` characters, `sed(1)` could help:

```
sed 's/&quot;/"/g; s/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/&amp;/\&/g'
```

***Update***: My original proposal was the following and had a bug:

```
sed 's/&amp;/\&/g; s/&quot;/"/g; s/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g'
```

This would convert "&amp;gt;" into ">" which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, with I've made a script to exchange those characters (the ones I saw across few files). I hope there're no more characters like that.

Comment: Is there a tool or libary to handle all of the special characters(list in specialcharacters.info)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try a tool like windows grep or textcrawler for this